# Asserting no methods were called

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

How do I assert that none of the methods of a stubbed/mocked object were called? For a single method it's fairly simple, just call `Stub(x => x.METHOD()).Repeat.Never()` but if you have bunch of methods or lots of overloaded methods it gets inconvenient.

Is there a neat workaround for this?

Comment: You should be able to create a strict mock with no expectations - calling anything on it will cause an expectation violation to be thrown.

Comment: @Lee - thanks, that's what I actually tried right after asking the question and it worked as a charm for me. Anyway, if you'd like to edit your response so it appears as an answer not comment, I'd accept it then

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't really used rhino-mocks, but as @Lee suggested in his comment you should be able to achieve the effect you're after using `StrictMock` without any other expectations.  So, given the following test:

```
public void TestStrickMock() {        
    var mockRepo = new MockRepository();

    // Create a StrictMock for the IDummy interface
    var mock = mockRepo.StrictMock<IDummy>();

    // Switch the mode of the mock repo from record to replay
    mockRepo.ReplayAll();

    // Invoke one of the methods on our mocked instance
    mock.Method1();
}
```

This test will fail, because `Method1` is called, when no expectation for the call has been set-up.  It fails with the error:

> TestStrickMock: Rhino.Mocks.Exceptions.ExpectationViolationException :
>   IDummy.Method1(); Expected #0, Actual #1.

Answer (score 0):

As others have said, use a `StrictMock`.

This passes.

```
var mockFoo = MockRepository.GenerateStrictMock<IFoo>();
mockFoo.VerifyAllExpectations();
```

This fails.

```
var mockFoo = MockRepository.GenerateStrictMock<IFoo>();
mockFoo.Bar();
mockFoo.VerifyAllExpectations();
```